# How do I create a Windows Interface Form that allows user to pick between 3 object types?

Tags: c#, oop, class, object, polymorphism

So here's the idea - The base class is Animal, and the derived classes are Bird and Dog.  I have a ComboBox for the user to choose which animal they'd like to create. How do I incorporate and connect all these all together at the Form level (frmAnimal.cs - public partial class frmAnimal : Form).

Depending upon this decision, it will also affect other buttons on the form, such as a button that calls .Move(), an overriden Animal method, that will call the correct Move() method depending upon whether Bird or Dog is chosen as the object type.

Does that make sense?

Comment: As best I understand your question, polymorphism already takes care of this for you. Just instantiate the particular derived class, and its `Move` method will be called automatically, whether overridden or not.

Comment: This question is very general and vague therefore difficult to answer. It may be worth posting your efforts so far and the particular areas you are struggling with.

Comment: Right, Cody, I am mostly trying to figure out how to incorporate polymorphism with user interaction through buttons and a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create and show a new form separate from the selection form? If so, you could make the form class generic, restricted to objects of an Animal type:

```
public abstract partial class AnimalFormBase<T>:Form where T:Animal {...}
```

You can then derive from that form to create animal-specific forms:

```
public partial class AnimalForm:AnimalFormBase<Animal> {...}
public partial class BirdForm:AnimalFormBase<Bird> {...}
public partial class DogForm:AnimalFormBase<Dog> {...}
```

If you want the same form but different controls, I would make the above classes derive from UserControl. Then, when the user changed the radio button, you could remove and replace the control for the old animal type with the one for the new animal. Either way, the generic ancestor AnimalFormBase can hold functionality pertaining to any Animal. It could technically contain controls, but I've found that custom inheritance in designer-rendered classes can get messy. Then, the three derivative forms could use the base functionality, add their own, and lay out the controls each one would present to the user.

Comment: I'm thinking of something more basic with the forms.  The form will be the same the entire time.  So, if the Move button is clicked, it use Bird or Dog or Animal's Move method depending upon which object is selected in the ComboBox.

Comment: Well, since all three are Animals, you could have a property of type Animal, that is reinstantiated (or pulled from some cache of existing objects of that type) to the correct type when the radio button changes, then the Move button handler would call the Move() method of the property. Then that button wouldn't care what the property's real type was; it knew enough to know it had a Move method (which must be available from Animal).

Answer (score 0):

My example is in vb.net (I am working on learning C#, but not "there" yet - the differences are not so great that this won't make sense, though . . .), but the essentials are failry universal. You have a base class Animal, and some classes that derive from animal. Define the .Move method on your base class. Then create your derived classes, which inherit the methods and public interface of your base class. Define an AnimalType Property in order to differentiate types on animal. FOr this very simple example, I used an Enum. In reality, this might be an Enum, or it could be a Database PK, or other unique identifier. Note that in practice, I would probably NOT make the superType Animal a member of the same enumeration as the derived classes. In a DataBase I would probably Make the derived objects "child" records related to a "Parent" animal record, for example):

```
Public Enum AnimalTypes
    Animal = 1
    Pig = 2
    Human = 3
End Enum

Public Class AnimalBase

    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property AnimalType() As AnimalTypes
        Get
            Return AnimalTypes.Animal
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Move(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
        ' . . . You movement code
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now your Derived Classes:

```
Public Class Pig
    Inherits AnimalBase

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property AnimalType() As AnimalTypes
        Get
            Return AnimalTypes.Pig
        End Get
    End Property

    'A property spcific to the pig class:
    Public ReadOnly Property PigOnEquality() As String
        Get
            Return "Some pigs are more equal!"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Human
    Inherits AnimalBase

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property AnimalType() As AnimalTypes
        Get
            Return AnimalTypes.Human
        End Get
    End Property

    'A property specific to the Human class:
    Public ReadOnly Property Shotgun() As String
        Get
            Return "Boom!"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Now, an AnimalFactory class, which cranks out instances of animal and classes which derive from type animal, as (one more time . . . type animal):

```
Public Class AnimalFactory

    Public Shared Function NewAnimal(ByVal AnimalType As AnimalTypes) As AnimalBase
        Select Case AnimalType
            Case AnimalTypes.Animal
                Return New AnimalBase
            Case AnimalTypes.Pig
                Return New Pig
            Case AnimalTypes.Human
                Return New Human
            Case Else
                Return New AnimalBase
        End Select
    End Function

End Class
```

The trick here is that the derived classes, as returned by the AnimalFacorty, are of type animal, but the implement all the propeties of thier true type, and if need be, can be cast to their true type. Now, your Form. Your form need not necessarily care which type of animal in returned either, if you are only accessing common methods defined on the base class. If you need to access a method specific to a derived class, you will need to perform a casting operation (which chould be the same (or very similar) in C# as in VB.net.

I have thrown some really silly examples in this form. There are also probably ways to avoid the Select Case (What I believe you would know as a Switch statement), but I have no idea what you are doing with your code, so this is simply an acedmic excercise . . .

```
 Public Class AnimalFarm ' My hilarious name for the FORM

     'Member variable for the currently selected instance of AnimalBase
     Private SelectedAnimal As AnimalBase

     Private Sub AnimalFarm_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

         'Using the enum to populate the comboBox:
         With Me.ComboBox1.Items
             .Add(AnimalTypes.Animal)
             .Add(AnimalTypes.Pig)
             .Add(AnimalTypes.Human)
         End With

     End Sub

     Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
         Dim AnimalType As AnimalTypes = Me.ComboBox1.SelectedItem
         Me.OnNewAnimalSelected(AnimalType)
     End Sub

     Private Sub OnNewAnimalSelected(ByVal AnimalType As AnimalTypes)
         SelectedAnimal = AnimalFactory.NewAnimal(AnimalType)

         'The form doesn't case what type of animal is being instantiated, so long
         'as the methods required are defined on the base class:
         MsgBox(SelectedAnimal.AnimalType.ToString)

         'Move the animal a bit, just for kicks:
         SelectedAnimal.Move(NewX, NewY)

         '  . . . But if you NEED the specific TYPE of animal:

         Select Case SelectedAnimal.AnimalType
             Case AnimalTypes.Human
                 Dim NewHuman As Human = CType(SelectedAnimal, Human)
                 MsgBox(NewHuman.Shotgun)

             Case AnimalTypes.Pig
                 Dim Piggy As Pig = CType(SelectedAnimal, Pig)
                 MsgBox(Piggy.PigOnEquality)
             Case Else
                 MsgBox("This Animal has nothing to say . . .")

         End Select
     End Sub

     Private Sub OnMoveAnimal(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
         SelectedAnimal.Move(X, Y)
     End Sub

 End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the great post!  It wasn't exactly what I was trying to do... but pretty close.